# Orchard CMS: 404 error after choosing manage menu

Tags: menu, navigation, http-status-code-404, orchardcms

In Orchard CMS I created a menu in navigation and populated it. But when I try to get back to manage the menu I get a 404 error saying `the resource is not found`. I created two other menus using advanced menu without a problem.

I then tried a duplicate hoping it might prompt me that one already exists. Now I cannot get to the resource to delete it nor can I create another menu to manage without the 404 error. I have no idea where to look. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a menu with a name containing a space or some other character not valid inside a URL. You can change that manually in database - table `Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuPartRecord`.